# Markers on google maps uploaded from excel(xlsx) file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking solution for my app. I need to upload excel file with data and then show all data from the file on google maps with multiple markers. 
I already found solution for second part (show multiple markers on google map):

```
 <script>

  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mymap');
    var mapOptions = {          
      center: new google.maps.LatLng (-33.865143, 151.209900),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var locations = [];
    locations.push ({name:"Bondi Beach", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856)});
    locations.push ({name:"Coogee Beach", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.923036, 151.259052)});
    locations.push ({name:"Cronulla Beach", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.028249, 151.157507)});
    locations.push ({name:"Manly Beach", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187)});

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: locations[i].latlng, map:map, title:locations[i].name});
    }
  }

  window.onload = initialize;

</script>
```

but how can I upload data from excel(I want user to submit file with data) and use it to show markers?
I am totally new to programming, so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS) to parse excel files in javascript. They have two seperate versions for `.xls` and `.xlsx` files.

- [SheetJS / js - xls](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls)
- [SheetJS/ js - xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

You can load the excell sheet using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). If you want to directly parse an excel sheet that the user inputs, you can use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object and its [`.readAsBinaryString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) method.

```js
document.getElementById("excel").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    //Verify that the selected file was an supported worksheet file.
    //You can check file.name and file.type properties for this validation

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;

        /* if binary string, read with type 'binary' */
        var workbook = XLS.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
        });
        
        console.log(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]["A1"].v); //Read the value of the A1 cell in the first worksheet
        /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.5/xls.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="excel" />
```

Comment: when I run this code on my browser I get error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" and file do not loaded. But when I load file here, in you sample, everything is ok. Where can be problem? Maybe you can help me figure it out how your sample will look/work with my code?

Comment: @Jaras, `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"` means that `document.getElementById("excel")` returns `null`. This is probably because you do not have an input element with `excel` id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use may way , if you like to use PHP then this is the code

```html
<script>

  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mymap');
    var mapOptions = {          
      center: new google.maps.LatLng (-33.865143, 151.209900),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

    var locations = [];

<?php
include 'excel_reader.php';       // include the class
$excel = new PhpExcelReader;      // creates object instance of the class
$excel->read('excel_file.xls');   // reads and stores the excel file data

// Test to see the excel data stored in $sheets property
$data = $excel->sheets;
while()
{
   echo "locations.push ({name:'".$data[i]['name']."', latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(".$data[i]['la'].", ".$data[i]['lng'].")});"
}

php?>
 for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: locations[i].latlng, map:map, title:locations[i].name});
    }
  }

  window.onload = initialize;

</script>
```

You can get excel_reader.php from this below link

http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/read-excel-file-data-php_pc